# Converting .py file to exe with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

It was converting my .py file to .exe file perfectly fine before,
but somehow now it is showing the following errors:

> WARNING: Tried to load multiple incompatible Qt wrappers. Some incorrect files may be copied.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "setmeup.py", line 5, in 
>       executables = [Executable("SciKit-Play-GUI.py")])

followed by some errors in cx_Freeze files in my directory......
Please HELP!

Comment: *It was working before, but now it's not.* - You are using source control, right? Go back and find the point where it stopped working.

Comment: Actually it is converting my other .py files just fine but the problem comes when i convert the files which has QtCore and QtGui modules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to convert a .py in exe you can use py2exe

use this command to compile :

```
setup.py py2exe
```

here is the setup.py file

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(    
    name = "...",
    version = '1.0',
    description = "...",
    author = "...",
    windows = [{'script': 'test.py'#, 'icon_resources': [(1, 'icon.ico')]
                }],
    zipfile = None,
    data_files=[],
    options = {
        'py2exe': {
            'optimize':2, 
            'bundle_files': 3,      
            'compressed': True, 
            'excludes':[],
            #'dll_excludes':['w9xpopen.exe']
            }
        }
)
```